# Accessing the length of a variable in a dataset

Tags: r

Is it possible to find the length of a variable in a dataset ? My dataset name is 'usairports' and I want to find the length of the 'ownership' variable.

```
length(usairports("ownership")
```

I tried this but it gave me the wrong output.
Thank you!

Comment: For vector: `length()`, For matrix: `nrow(), ncol()`, For array: `dim()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```r
length(usairports$ownership)

or

length(usairports[['ownership']])
```

Comment: alternatively if you want to know the variable value maximum length then you can use `str_length` with `max`, something like below `max(str_length(iris$Species))`